# Is there any way to get global ranks from Pytorch distributed (nccl) group?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-training

Suppose we have a Pytorch distributed group object that initialized by `torch.distributed.new_group([a,b,c,d])`, is there any way to get the global ranks `a,b,c,d` from this group?

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch offers an `torch.distributed.distributed_c10d._get_global_rank` function can be used in this case:

```
import torch.distributed as dist
def get_all_ranks_from_parallel_group(group):
    rank=0
    results=[]
    try:
        while True:
            results.append(dist.distributed_c10d._get_global_rank(group, rank))
            rank+=1
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
    return results
```